# How to change the label languages on the Here Map?

Tags: android, here-api

As stated on the official website: [HERE SDK does not require any actions from developers to set the appropriate language as it automatically detects the current device language setting and applies the same language within the SDK if it is supported.](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/coverage-label-languages.html)
When I change the language settings on the phone, the language of the map in my application does not change.
I also tried changing the locale in onCreate settings. And I didn’t succeed either.

```
        Locale locale = new Locale("ru_RU");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't the language change?

[image: Map image]

Comment: inside the locale please specify the language code as per the below documentation.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow, Roman. Can you precise which labels you expect to show up in Russian locale, and at which location? Maybe put a screenshot?

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport Thanks for the help, but I added the language code to the locale according to what was written on the android site. If this is not correct, please correct me. Or write a link where you can get the correct language code

Comment: @MichaelP.Bazos Thanks for the warm welcome. I need to translate the map into Russian. Namely, the names of streets, districts, and settlements. Screenshot attached to the description of the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This starts working with version 4.1.6
You need to specify the language in MapSceneConfig and add it when loading the map scene

```
private void loadMapScene() {
MapSceneConfig mapSceneConfig = new MapSceneConfig();
mapSceneConfig.mainLanguageCode = LanguageCode.RU_RU;
mapSceneConfig.fallbackLanguageCode = LanguageCode.RU_RU;

mapView.getMapScene().loadScene(MapStyle.NORMAL_DAY, mapSceneConfig, new MapScene.LoadSceneCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadScene(@Nullable MapScene.ErrorCode errorCode) {
        if (errorCode == null) {
            hereMap = new HereMap(MainActivity.this, mapView);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "onLoadScene failed: " + errorCode.toString());
        }
    }
});
```

}

Comment: What about flutter?